# RestTemplate.postForObject() works, but exchange() does not

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, web

I have an application that sends api calls to another application, with this code:

```
objreq.setReq(request);
HttpEntity<Request> entity = new HttpEntity<Request>(objreq, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

where headers contains application/json of course.

The problem is, is that the objreq is set correctly, however, when it calls the other api:

```
@PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Response> insertRequest(
          @RequestBody @Valid Request request) {
    requestService.insertRequest(request);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseSuccess<>());
  }
```

all the fields are null. This is really annoying as the fields are set correctly in the request, but in everything is null in the response.

**Note:** this code works fine

```
restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
```

Would like to know why the exchange does not work, unfortunately I don't have much experience with RestTemplate, so not sure if the issue is here. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ok-T-), the `ok(T body)` builds the response body from the parameter `T body`, you're passing a `ResponseSuccess` object, which may be the problem here, I don't know what's inside the `ResponseSuccess` class (couldn't find the docs for this class so I can't be really sure where in this class the problem might be) but I'd look for the problem there.

Comment: Thanks for you comment Minato, really appreciate it. The ok(T body) seems to be working fine, as calling it from Postman works perfectly.

Comment: @Ramonster have you tried the methods, like `response.getBody()`. Its strange that the method `postForObject` works properly but the `exchange` returns null. The only high level difference is `exchange` wraps the reply inside a `ResponseEntity` object rather than its generic behaviour is that(leaving the technical details aside), while `postForObject` directly converts the reply into the said `Object` i.e. `String`.

Comment: Thanks @Minato, that insight is really helpful. I am unsure what you mean by trying response.getBody though. The backend api returns an error because the Object it receives is set to null, but the object is set correctly when using postForObject()

Comment: Can you try this method `RequestEntity<Request> entity = new RequestEntity(objreq.getBody(), headers, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(url));` then `restTemplate.exchange(entitiy, String.class);`

Comment: Thanks for your help Minato. Finally Figured it out. Basically, we using code developed by a third party..., anyways, the had two different classes with very very similar names. So with postForObject, the correct object was sent, but with exchange it gets mapped/parsed to a particular type, which unfortunately in my code was incorrect